# Adding onclickListeners to view elements outside of activity (own class)

Tags: java, android

First of all i'm not even sure if this is possible.

I'm trying the achieve the following: Create my own seperate dependency which dynamically adds onclick listeners to certain elements for which the id's are known. (Entirely outside an activity; see the following:)

```
public class Example extends Application
```

What i managed so far is accessing specific view elements from within my own class. For this i am using the LayoutInflator:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
View element = view.findViewById(R.id.readthis);
```

After retrieving the specific view element i add an onclickListener (in this example a button)

```
button.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(button));

View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button.setText("text now set.. ");
            }
        };
    }
```

Setting the thing works fine. But i'm guessing the layout inflator actually creates a copy of the view and i'm ***not*** getting direct references to the currently active view objects. Which means the onclickListener isn't being triggered because it's not set to the proper object.

I'm fairly new to Android and hence the question whether i'm wasting my time or if there's a way to get this to work. Would love to get some advice on this.

Comment: can you be more clear about what you want to achieve

Comment: Where did you inflating the layout "activity_main"?
depends on that it can be answered.
Wherever you are inflating the view, the onclick will stick to that view.

Comment: Sorry if i 'm being unclear. What i want to achieve a dependency which only has to be initialised once and after that it generates onclickListeners on all view elements that are specified in a config file. So basically i do not have or want access to the activities or modify existing activity code in any way. It has to be an entirely separate functionality.

Comment: @gvsharma I am inflating it in a separate class which extends from Application. However; I would like to get the current active activity but i have no idea how to achieve that. (hence why it's hardcoded in the example :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I was looking at this the wrong way. Solved it by implementing `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and registering my class by `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this)`

Now i can access the views from the activity context within the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your question right, but you can expose setter methods in the activity that contains the relevant views, to set a click listener from outside. Something like this:

```
public void setViewClickListener(OnClickListener clickListener) {
        if (myView != null) {
            myView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        }
    }
```

And then in your separate class, call this method with the relevant click listener.

Comment: Thanks for this. However i do not have or want access to existing activities. The endgoal is a dependency which has to be loaded only once and manipulates activities.

Comment: i understand your requirement....Like how spring does in case of Java enterprise applications which loads once and will handle all the things like generating beans and handling life cycle of beans and killing that once it not going to useful. Is it?